# Append always returning false statement

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to remove duplicates from a given list and return a new list.

e.g.:
 `?-removeDuplicates([a,a,b,c],L).` should return `L=[a,b,c]`

```
removeDuplicates([],[]).
removeDuplicates([Head|Tail], List) :- 
       ( 
         member(Head,Tail), 
         removeDuplicates(Tail, prevList),        
         append([], prevList, List)
       );
       (
         not(member(Head,Tail)), 
         removeDuplicates(Tail,prevList),
         append(Head, prevList, List)
       ).
```

In order to do that, I tried to implement an or statement.

If Head exists in Tail, then I call the recursion and my new List is the same as prevList. On the other hand, if Head does not exist in Tail, then I call the recursion and append Head to prevList and put the result in List.

For some reason, I always get false as an answer.

Can you please help me understand what I do wrong?

Comment: `prevList` is an atom, atoms cannot be changed. All variables always start with a Capital Letter.

Comment: Nice! I don't know how I missed that..
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, Head should be transformed into a list when I append :D That was my other problem!

Comment: Additionally, `OR` statements, `;` as you correctly identified, are best combined with conditional statements like this `((if) -> then ; else)`, as `()` just say "this is a single grouped term", they don't automatically trigger evaluation at runtime. For example, you can say `H = (somecall(Result), processResult(Result), some other stuff, H` where the second call to H is the one actually evaluating what you assigned it earlier. This is to allow you to dynamically build calls, which is more advanced stuff you will encounter later when getting into "Prolog generics" by lack of a better term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the tracer, your program fails when this happen `removeDuplicates([], prevList)` at the end of the recursion, when the list is empty. I think you are overcomplicating the problem. This could be easily solved with few lines of codes:

```
removeDup([],[]).
removeDup([H|T],[H|T1]):-
    \+member(H,T),
    removeDup(T,T1).
removeDup([H|T],L):-
    member(H,T),
    removeDup(T,L).

?- removeDup([1,2,3,4,2,3,5,4,0],L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 0]
false
```

Or, even shorter, using if:

```
removeDup([],[]).
removeDup([H|T],[H1|T1]):-
    (   
      \+member(H,T) ->
      H = H1,
      removeDup(T,T1);
      removeDup(T,[H1|T1])
    ).
```